# Algorithm to find a square root of a number?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

The only algorithm that I know for this problem is the Newton's method (make a guess, then improve it until it's good enough).

Any other ideas (use any language you prefer)?

PS: Of course I don't have any use case for this, I'm just researching it for academic reasons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is always the [John Carmack method](http://www.codemaestro.com/reviews/9), which is a highly efficient variation upon the Newton method.

Comment: But then you'd have to invert it.

Comment: Or multiply it by x. x / sqrt(x) = sqrt(x)

Answer (score 5):

Several can be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareRootAlgorithms.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check  algorithms in [Methods of computing square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Approximations_that_depend_on_IEEE_representation).

This is fast `C` Log base `2` implementation of the Newton's Method:

```
double sqrt(const double x)  
{
  union
  {
    int i;
    double x;
  } u;

  u.x = x;
  u.i = (1<<29) + (u.i >> 1) - (1<<22); 
  return u.x;
}
```